# register and insert category manually

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am registering custom taxonomies ....

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_tax' );

function create_book_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'genre',
        'product',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Genre' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );

?>
```

It is successfully creating Taxonomy of **Genre** under **Product** Post type.

Now I want to manually add categories inside **Genre** and it will also be heirarchical so I can again insert new category inside newly created category.

Please tell me how to manually create category.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to add it only once, so you have to check if it exists. Then you can use [wp_insert_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) function

```
if ( !term_exists('MyCategory1', 'genre') ) {
    wp_insert_term('MyCategory1', 'genre');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you noticed or if it matters but you forgot to close the code's bracket.

```
        )
    );

?>
```

to

```
        )
    );
  }
?>
```